# How to pass string from string.xml through a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView thats extends to a grid layout to show an image and a  text, it has an onclick listener that leads to a second activity where I have a couple of views that are populated by data sent by the adapter, I got the image to pass through, and a static text that i set through

```
lstItem.add(new Item("Item1","Category",R.strings.item1Des,R.drawable.image1));
```

The image passes through but the string doesn't.

My adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;
    private List<Item> mData ;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardveiw_item_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv_tem_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.img_item_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Item_Activity.class);

                // passing data to the book activity
                intent.putExtra("Title",mData.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Description",mData.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
                // start the activity
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_item_title;
        ImageView img_item_thumbnail;
        CardView cardView ;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_item_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id) ;
            img_item_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img_id);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);


        }
    }

}
```

My item activity (that opens after onclick):

```
private TextView tvtitle,tvdescription,tvcategory;
private ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_);

    tvtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
    tvdescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    tvcategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
    tvdescription.setKeyListener(null);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemthumbnail);

    Object clipboardService = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)clipboardService;
    Button copyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clipboard_copy_button);


    // Recieve data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
    String Description = intent.getExtras().getString("Description");
    int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Thumbnail") ;

    // Setting values

    tvtitle.setText(Title);
    tvdescription.setText(Description);
    img.setImageResource(image);

    copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  }
    });
}
```

My item class

```
public class Item{

    private String Title;
    private String Category ;
    private int Description ;
    private int Thumbnail ;


    public Item(String title, String category, int description, int thumbnail) {
        Title = title;
        Category = category;
        Description = description;
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public int getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return Thumbnail;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        Category = category;
    }

    public void setDescription(int description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I used getString (R.strings.id) instead of just R.strings.Id.

Answer (score 2):

In this line of `onBindViewHolder()` in your adapter class:

```
intent.putExtra("Description", mData.get(position).getDescription());
```

`mData.get(position).getDescription()` is an integer number representing the id in resources of a string. So it is **not** the actual string.
Change it to:

```
String desc = mContext.getResources().getString(mData.get(position).getDescription());
intent.putExtra("Description", desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing id(i.e int) of your string i.e `R.strings.item1Des`, You have to first get id from intent extras and then obtain its value by calling `getString(R.strings.item1Des)` method where you're going to use this string like

```
String Description = getString(intent.getIntExtra("Description",0));
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work. Your description is Int (only reference to string resource)

```
// Recieve data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
    int Description = intent.getExtras().getInt("Description");
    int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Thumbnail") ;

    // Setting values

    tvtitle.setText(Title);
    tvdescription.setText(getString(Description));
    img.setImageResource(image);
```